# How to add MongoDB in Qwik?

Tags: qwik, qwikjs

I'm new in Qwik, I want to make a full stack web application (Real time chat application), The problem is I do not know how to add MongoDB or MySQL, Firebase.

I try to make express server, but is there any way? anyone can help me please

Thank you in advance